# I am not able to query a pre-created database using SQLiteAssetHelper

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am not able to query a pre-created database. I created a SQLite database using SQLiteDatabaseBrowser and I populated it. The following query works in the SQLiteDatabaseBrowser:

```
SELECT png FROM flags64 WHERE iso3='jpn' LIMIT 1
```

I moved the file in the folder "../assets/databases" in the android project into the Android Studio. This is the code used to query the database from my android app:

```
public class myStickerDatabase extends SQLiteAssetHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mysticker.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public myStickerDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    public Bitmap getFlag(String iso3) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(String.format("SELECT png FROM flags64 WHERE iso3 = '%s' LIMIT 1", iso3), null);

        c.moveToFirst();

        byte[] png = c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndex("png"));

        ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(png);
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
    }
}
```

Debugging the code the query does not return any records.

**Update**
It would seem that the database is not copied to the device.
The database size is about 250kb, but the copy in the device is about 24kb. Why?

[image: Android Studio]

Comment: Have you tried deleting mysticker.db  and the mysticker.db-journal from the device and rerunning? (perhaps the .sqlite and .sqlite-journal files as well). Could all the files having a date/time of 1970-01-18 13:17 indicate anything?

Comment: Check that the file in the assets/database has circa 250K file size, you might have forgotten to save before copying file.